# Flux density and albedo

Tags: atmospheric-radiation

**To save the Earth, the surface of the Earth has been covered by silver foil. The foil has a albedo of 0.9. What is the flux density emitted from the surface of the Earth (assume temperature of 50 deg C)?**

So I thought I could use Stefan Boltzmann law and just plugg in my values and got 569, but this is not correct. What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In your calculation, did you use albedo correctly? Remember, [albedo is the ratio of reflected radiation to total radiation](https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Albedo), and 1-albedo is the ratio of absorbed radiation to total radiation.

Edit: Make sure you are plugging the numbers in correctly too.